# How to use the new @ClientWindowScoped annotation in applications?

Tags: jsf

Jakarta Faces 4.0 introduced a new `@ClientWindowScoped` annotation. However, searching the specification and implementations, I haven't found any example of its practical use in applications.

Maybe it's not only the case to annotate a bean with this annotation, but also to manipulate the `jfwid` request parameter through some provided API. If that's the case, can anyone provide a simple example of how it can be used or point to an article that does?

Comment: Hey Marcos, I had the same question so I modified the question a bit and added some more tags to hopefully get some more exposure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally all you need is to activate the ClientWindowScope in the web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>jakarta.faces.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE</param-name>
    <param-value>url</param-value>
</context-param>
```

With Wildfly 27/28.0.1 I needed to use the *bean-discovery-mode* **all** in beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_4_0.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all"/>
```

Maybe this is a bug, because the *ClientWindowScope* is annotated with *NormalScope* which is indeed a [Bean defining annotation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#bean_defining_annotations).

Or keep *bean-discovery-mode* **annotated** (default) and create a *sterotype* with the *ClientWindowScoped* annotation.

```
@ClientWindowScoped
@Stereotype
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface WindowScoped {    }
```

Now you can use add *@WindowScoped* in the default (annotated) bean discovery mode.

If you use PrimeFaces you could also have a look at the [PrimeClientWindowLifecycleFactory](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/core/clientwindow?id=client-window) which ensures that the jfwid url parameter is forced on first page load and generated links will start in new browser or tab a new window session.

Comment: AFAICS ClientWindowScoped must be a bean defining annotation like mentioned in the specs: all other normal scope types

Comment: Yeah you are right the ClientWindowScope is annotated with NormalScope. So this might be a bug in Wildfly 27 and 28.01. I will fix my answer.